# Path ambiguity through symbolic links

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, symlink, cd

I have noticed a strange behavior in UNIX systems:

```
I'm standing in /noob/
I have a symbolic link to a folder (A@ -> /B/C/D/A)
I enter the folder via my symlink (cd A) 
pwd says /noob/A/
In /B/C/D/A/ i have a file abc which I can see now.
I want to copy it to /noob/
I type cp abc ..
I type cd ..
I end up in /noob/ which is empty - but the file ended up in /B/C/D/ ???
```

How come this ambiguity as to where cp and cd points when given .. as argument? I find it confusing. Can anyone explain it in terms I'll understand? (=simple)

All the best, and please forgive a UNIX-noob a stupid question. Lasse

Comment: Sorry - my lines were merged into one flow.

Comment: I have fixed that and answered to your question, let me know if it is clear! Have a look at how the commands react with the different options ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's have a look at how `cd` command does behave by looking at the `help` menu. What we are looking for is option `-L` (the default behavior) and option `-P`

> ```
> $ help cd cd: cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@]] [dir]
> Change the shell working directory.
>
> ...
> ...
>
> Options:
>     -L      force symbolic links to be followed: resolve symbolic links in
>     DIR after processing instances of `..'
>     -P      use the physical directory structure without following symbolic
>     links: resolve symbolic links in DIR before processing instances
>     of `..'
> ...
> ...
> ```

**Important section**

> ```
> The default is to follow symbolic links, as if `-L' were specified.
> `..' is processed by removing the immediately previous pathname component
> back to a slash or the beginning of DIR.
>
> Exit Status:
> ...
> ```

As you can see the default behavior of `cd` is not what you think it is since he will manipulate the `$PWD` variable accessed by `pwd` command in his own way, at each step you can run `pwd` command or do an `echo $PWD` to see how it reacts with the different `cd` commands hereunder.

Let's play with `cd` command:

We start from the following folder, with a sym link:

```
[/home/arobert/test/noob] >
ls -ltra
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 5 arobert arobert 4096  5月 11 09:48 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 arobert arobert   26  5月 11 09:48 A -> /home/arobert/link/B/C/D/A
drwxrwxr-x 2 arobert arobert 4096  5月 11 10:03 .
```

**USAGE EXAMPLES:**

```
[/home/arobert/test/noob] >
cd A
[/home/arobert/test/noob/A] >
cd ..
[/home/arobert/test/noob] >
cd -L A
[/home/arobert/test/noob/A] >
cd ..
[/home/arobert/test/noob] >
cd -P A
[/home/arobert/link/B/C/D/A] >
cd -P ..
[/home/arobert/link/B/C/D] >
cd /home/arobert/test/noob/
[/home/arobert/test/noob] >
cd A
[/home/arobert/test/noob/A] >
cd -P ..
[/home/arobert/link/B/C/D] >
```

Now let's play with `readlink` and `cp` command:

Let's say we have entered the symlink that points to `A -> /home/arobert/link/B/C/D/A` in which we have a file `a`

```
[/home/arobert/test/noob/A] >
ls -ltra
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 3 arobert arobert 4096  5月 11 09:55 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 arobert arobert    0  5月 11 10:10 a
drwxrwxr-x 2 arobert arobert 4096  5月 11 10:10 .
```

from this folder let's look at where does point `.` and `..` by using `readlink -f` command:

```
[/home/arobert/test/noob/A] >
readlink -f .
/home/arobert/link/B/C/D/A

[/home/arobert/test/noob/A] >
readlink -f ..
/home/arobert/link/B/C/D
```

By consequence, when you run from the location `/home/arobert/test/noob/A` equivalent to `/home/arobert/link/B/C/D/A` the command `cp a ..` the file will be moved to `/home/arobert/link/B/C/D` as `..` points to it.

What you can do now:

- Use absolute path with your `cp` command to avoid bad surprise.
- Call the command from `/home/arobert/test/noob/` directory using

For example:

```
[/home/arobert/test/noob] >
cp A/a .
```

as `readlink -f .` points to the correct folder

```
[/home/arobert/test/noob] >
readlink -f .
/home/arobert/test/noob
```

**Result:**

```
[/home/arobert/test/noob] >
ls -ltra
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 5 arobert arobert 4096  5月 11 09:48 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 arobert arobert   26  5月 11 09:48 A -> /home/arobert/link/B/C/D/A
-rw-rw-r-- 1 arobert arobert    0  5月 11 10:13 a
drwxrwxr-x 2 arobert arobert 4096  5月 11 10:13 .
```

Comment: Thank You very much! This was a very good and exhaustive answer! I
learned a lot now!

I suspect I'm not the only one getting confused reading manual pages... they are very formal.

Comment: And so I learned that cr-s are turned into blank spaces in the forum.

Comment: @dr_xemacs: if I have answered your question could you accept my answer? Thanks